# What is the specification for "attribute/value notation" mentioned in RFC 2046?

Tags: mime-types, mime

I'm looking for the rules on how to correctly parse [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type strings.  Note that this is required for use outside of email (in this case AMQP).

In [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html) it refers to "attribute/value notation":

> After the media type and subtype names, the remainder
> of the header field is simply a set of parameters, specified in an
> attribute=value notation.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious in RFC 2046 or this is specified elsewhere, but I can't seem to find any syntax rules for this.

For example, can values be quoted? If so, which quotes are valid (`'` or `"`)?  Also what white space is valid and how much?

Most things like this in RFCs usually have some BNF defining them, but I just don't see it for MIME type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attribute=value` part is actually defined in the [RFC 2045 - 5.1.  Syntax of the Content-Type Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1) as mentioned in the introduction of RFC 2046. There you see a detailed description of how `attribute` and `value` are defined:

> ```
>  parameter := attribute "=" value
>
>  attribute := token
>               ; Matching of attributes
>               ; is ALWAYS case-insensitive.
>
>  value := token / quoted-string
>
>  token := 1*<any (US-ASCII) CHAR except SPACE, CTLs,
>              or tspecials>
> ```

Where `quoted-string` is defined in [RFC 882](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822):

> ```
>  quoted-string = <"> *(qtext/quoted-pair) <">; Regular qtext or
>                                              ;   quoted chars.
> ```

Comment: I was off by one. 